# Python : Most efficient way to get list of combinations?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I have a dictionary :

```
diff_params = {0: [a, b], 
               1: [c, d]}
```

Each key is a setting_name, and each value is a specific setting. I would like to be able to make a list like:

```
[[a, c], 
 [a, d],
 [b, c],
 [b, d]]
```

I can't figure out how to do cleanly when I have 3 or 4 or 5 settings and each setting has several options.

Comment: what are those colons for? are these strings? edit `[0 : a, 1: c]` doesn't make sense in python

Comment: My mistake, they weren't supposed to be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are more specifically looking for [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which can be used like this with [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
from itertools import product

result = product(*diff_params.values())
```

You may need to cast the result if you really want a list of list (surrounding `list` is useless if you are using Python 2 because `map()` return a list):

```
result = list(map(list, result))
```